LaTeX : How to conditionnaly include an image in a TeX file?
I'm sure this is not so complicated :
I'm searching to create an images gallery in which unavailable or missing image files are replaced by a default image. Something like :
if <image file> undefined then includegraphics[]{default.jpg} else includegraphics[]{image.jpg}

But I cannot found the correct syntax for the compiler to test the presence of the required file in the folder and then choose the default if necessary.
I hope it's possible to do that in a (La)TeX file. But what can't be done with TeX (except coffee) ?
Thanks for help.

\IfFileExists{image.png}{\includegraphics{image.png}}{\includegraphics{default.png}}

Excellent ! It works well. Thanks a lot. Where can I found a list of all the available commands like /IfFileExist{} or a manual about it ?

It's part of core latex so any tutorial, or texdoc clsguide section 4.6, see also texdoc usrguide  usrguide and clsguide are part of the base latex release.

Thanks one more time.
